how to get controller vibration data coming from an application?
I am having a lot of plobem trying to figure out how can i use the vibration data sent from a game to the controller to move others motors. The problem is finding the data themself.
I tried using xinput and some other libraries but without luck

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
